# Golang: timestamp add not working

Tags: timezone, timeout, golang, timestamp

the task is this, I need to add 5 minutes to the timestamp, but whatever I do, the time does not change, what am I doing wrong?

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/AavonfZk2bn

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The call to `parse.Add` at line 12 in your example should be changed to something like:

```
parse=parse.Add(5 * time.Minute)
```

the `.Add` method doesn't alter the time struct in place, it returns a new struct with the duration added which your original example was throwing away.

See [this GO webiste](https://play.golang.org/p/oIL8oyiCX7o) for a quick example: